# About $\int_0^{\pi/2} x^2 \cos ^{2n} (x) \, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, asymptotics

I searched the stack exchange but did not find anything about the computation of :

$$\int _0^{\pi /2}x^2 \cos ^{2n} x\, \mathrm{d}x$$ or at least an equivalent as $n \to \infty$.

As I have never been good at such computations, does anyone already has computed (or found an equivalent) of this quantity ?

Comment: **Hint:** Using integration by parts twice and then using [Wallis' integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals) should give you the closed form.

Comment: The main contribution to the integral comes from a neighborhood of $x=0$, and an application of the Laplace method yields $$\begin{align} \int_0^{\pi/2} x^2 \cos^{2n}(x)\,dx &= \int_0^{\pi/2} x^2 \exp\{2n\log \cos x\}\,dx \\ &\sim \int_0^{\infty} x^2 \exp\{ -nx^2 \}\,dx \\ &= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4 n^{3/2}} \end{align}$$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using (see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricPowerFormulas.html))
$$\cos^{2n}(x)=\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}+\frac{2}{4^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{n-k}\cos(2kx)$$
it suffices to evaluate for $1\leq k\leq n$
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}x^2\cos(2kx)\,dx=
\left[\frac{4k^2x^2\sin(2kx)+4kx\cos(2kx)-2\sin(2kx)}{(2k)^3}\right]_0^{\pi/2}=
\frac{\pi(-1)^k}{4k^2}.$$
Hence
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} x^2 \cos ^{2n}(x) \, dx=
\frac{\pi^3}{24\cdot4^n}\binom{2n}{n}+\frac{\pi}{2\cdot 4^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n}{n-k}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k^2}$$
that is a rational linear combination of $\pi^3$ and $\pi$.

P.S. If you just need the limit of the integral use [dominated convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem):
$0\leq f_n(x):=x^2 \cos ^{2n}(x)\leq x^2$ and $f_n(x)\to 0$ in $[0,\pi/2)$ implies
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^{\pi/2} x^2 \cos ^{2n}(x) \, dx=0.$$

Comment: I knew the limit was $0$, but thank you for the computation, thus I will find an equivalent of this, which is not dificult

Comment: @M.LTA I am glad that you appreciate my efforts. Any further doubt?

Comment: Nope, I didn't check the computations but I don't care, I totally forgot that I could linearized the $cos ^{2n}$ !